How to make protocol compatible with bounded TypeVar
While creating stubs files, I ran into this problem
In this code (example), I need to make "SupportsPlaceholderValue" usable as a type argument to specify the return type of result
To recreate the expected solution ignore the error of subclassing a protocol from a non-protocol class
import abc
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")
T_co = typing.TypeVar("T_co", covariant=True)
TraceTypeT = typing.TypeVar("TraceTypeT", bound="TraceType")

class TraceType(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def from_tensors(self, tensors: list[typing.Any]) -> typing.Any: ...
    def placeholder_value(self) -> typing.Any: ...

# Protocol class "SupportsPlaceholderValue" cannot derive from non-Protocol class "TraceType"
class SupportsPlaceholderValue(TraceType, typing.Protocol[T_co]):  # <-- error
    def placeholder_value(self) -> T_co: ...

class MyTraceType(typing.Generic[TraceTypeT], TraceType):
    def __init__(self, *components: TraceTypeT) -> None:
        self.components: tuple[TraceTypeT, ...]

    # error: SupportsPlaceholderValue[T@result]" is not assignable to "TraceType"
    def result(self: MyTraceType[SupportsPlaceholderValue[T]]) -> list[T]:  # ???
        # .py implementation
        return [c.placeholder_value() for c in self.components]

Is it possible to make this work? Do I need to use the type: ignore flag? or is it necessary to change the approach?
Try to make the typevar can be a Protocol, but the type checker is not working correctly
TraceTypeT = typing.TypeVar("TraceTypeT", bound="TraceType | typing.Protocol")

I have thought about creating a bounded typevar to a Protocol class identical to TraceType, but I don't know if it is a good idea to make it assignable to classes that do not inherit from TraceType.

Sounds like you should make TraceType an abstract base class, with placeholder_value an abstract method, instead of trying to define a protocol that can only apply to subclasses of TraceType.

The problem is that I need to do this many times, it would not be profitable to do all the generic methods
